# How to replace values in a list with an other time increasing list of data

Tags: python

I have a list of data (numbers) comming from a sensor.
I need to transforme that data into a list in which i have control, exemple:

```
values=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
results=[0]*10
```

what i need to do is replace results with numbers from values from 1 to 10 and then start replacing de results value from 11 to 20. exemple:
results=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
and then

```
results=[11,12,13,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

the code that i have right now is as follows:

```
from ctypes import sizeof
import time
valores=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
#valores=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,11,12,13,14]
teste =[]
i = 0
#print(len(valores))
for i, x in enumerate(valores):
    if len(teste)<10:
        #print(valores[i])
        teste.insert(i,valores[i])
        time.sleep(1)
        print(teste)
        i = i + 1
    elif len(teste)==10:
        for j, y in enumerate(teste):
            teste[j]=valores[i]
            time.sleep(1)
            print(teste)
            i=i+1
            if i==len(valores):
                break
        break
```

But i want the teste list to be defined in the beginning

Comment: "*i want the teste list to be defined in the beginning*" -> `teste = values[:10]` ?

Comment: Do you need `teste` to be of fixed length or just to be the length of `valores` if it is less than ten and maximum ten? *Note*: you should not increment `i` in a for loop, it is going to get you in trouble since the for loop is already incrementing `i`

Comment: yes, the teste size is fixed.

Comment: let me explain better
i have a flow meter device retrieving data every second.
the data is beeing stored in a list, every time that list has 5 values, i need to sum the new 5 values and stored them in a new list
exemple:
seconds=[1,2,3,4,5]
minutes=[15,0,0,0,0]

afterwards:
seconds=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
minutes=[15,40,0,0,0]

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out exactly what you need since the comment is different from your code. Overall, I think the task is not too complicated, I just can't really answer until I get it completely. Can you share an example (or a few) of input and output in the way that you have function `output_data = some_function(input_data)` the we can help defining how to code this `some_function()`.